# notepad++ with node using sockets error

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, socket.io

Im trying to send a message from a webpage to a node server. Im using notepad++. My html looks likes this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/0.9.16/socket.io.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function one()
        {
            var socket = io.connect('http://192.168.201.91:8001');//connect the socket to url
            socket.emit('Stream', {"StreamName": "Livestream1"});//send the socket with the parameter and data
        }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        </br>
        </br>
        <center><button type ="Button"  onclick="one()">Stream name 1</button></center>
</body>
</html>
```

These are supposed to connect to a node server which is on the given address.
In node I have set up the sockets like this:

```
var io_client = require('socket.io').listen('8001');
io_client.on('Stream', function(data)
{
        var name = data;
        console.log(data);
});
```

Do I need to use socket.io-client for this to get a message from the html to the server and the server to listen??
Any help would be great

Comment: what is `HTML` here ?

Comment: code updated to show the html not just the javascript inside it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were two problems in your question.

1.) Use latest version of `socket-io` client. Older leads to `bad request` error. use following

```
<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.0.6.js"></script>
```

2.) your code in server should be like this.

```
var server = require('socket.io').listen('8001');
server.on('connection',function(socket){
    console.log('connection');
    socket.on('Stream', function(data){
       var name = data;
       console.log(data);
    });
});
```

You were expecting the `Streams` event on server itself. But it'll occur on that socket from where it has been sent.